# Сокращение записи при вызове функции

Tags: c#

Добрый день!

Есть код, подскажите пожалуйста какую технологию языка C# мне использовать и как она называется, чтобы процесс назначения переменной `enum` реализовать при вызове функции `Summ()` класса `AnyClass`

```
enum AnyEnum
{
    FIRST_VALUE,
    SECOND_VALUE
}

internal class AnyClass
{
    int a = 0;
    internal void Summ(AnyEnum enum)
    {
        if(enum == AnyEnum.FIRST_VALUE)            
            a = 5;            
        else if(enum == AnyEnum.SECOND_VALUE)            
            a = 10;            
    }
}


internal class MainClass
{
    int f = 0;

    public MainClass(int f)
    {
        this.f = f;

        AnyEnum enum = AnyEnum.FIRST_VALUE;
        if(this.f > 5)
            enum = AnyEnum.SECOND_VALUE;

        AnyClass anyClass = new AnyClass();
        anyClass.Summ(enum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `anyClass.Summ((this.f > 5)? AnyEnum.SECOND_VALUE : AnyEnum.FIRST_VALUE);` - ternary operator

Comment: Не понятна цель. Есть делегаты, в крайнем случае есть "указатели", или там токены процедур.

Comment: @nick_n_a цель сократить запись, изучить новый принцип в языке, если у Вас найдется время на то чтобы показать то как бы Вы использовали выше перечисленные .... буду Вам очень благодарен.

Comment: @Igor большое спасибо, это просто сокращенный вариант записи if else? он как-нибудь называется? не могу нагуглить сиснтаксис с несколькими else if

Comment: @K.Oleg вместо нескольких `if` можно использовать `switch`

Comment: @Igor нашел https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ty67wk28.aspx нету возможности использования else if

Comment: @K.Oleg - `anyClass.Summ((this.f < 5)? AnyEnum.FIRST_VALUE : ((this.f < 10)? AnyEnum.SECOND_VALUE : AnyEnum.THIRD_VALUE));`